# Find Students who have registered in multiple subject by subject name

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

```
StudentID | SubCode | SubName
-------------------------------
   1          1       Math
   1          2       Science
   1          3       English
   2          1       Math
   2          2       Science
   3          2       Science
   4          1       Math
   4          3       English
```

This is my subject table.

How can I find students who have registered as following

1. Students who have registered in only Maths
2. Students who have registered In Maths And English
3. Students who have registered In Science And Maths And English

in a single SQL query.

I tried as this way

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    `stud_id` FROM  `subj_assign` 
WHERE  
   `subj_id` =  '1,2'
   AND STATUS =  '1'
ORDER BY  
   `subj_assign`.`stud_id` ASC
```

Comment: Where's your effort so far?

Comment: You need one query for every point (3 query's) or one query for all?

Comment: Single query for all three points

Comment: 1 query per point makes much more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try these two queries, both are similar but shows the data in different ways:

```
SELECT StudentID,
       CASE
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN SubCode IN( 1, 2, 3 ) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) = 3 THEN 'All'
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN SubCode IN( 1, 3 ) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) = 2 THEN 'MathsEnglish'
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN SubCode IN( 1 ) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) = 1 THEN 'Maths'
       END AS subjects
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY StudentID
HAVING subjects IS NOT NULL;

SELECT StudentID,
       CASE
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN SubCode IN( 1, 2, 3 ) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) = 3 THEN 'YES'
         ELSE 'NO'
       END AS `all`,
       CASE
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN SubCode IN( 1, 3 ) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) = 2 THEN 'YES'
         ELSE 'NO'
       END AS `MathsEnglish`,
       CASE
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN SubCode IN( 1 ) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) = 1 THEN 'YES'
         ELSE 'NO'
       END AS `Maths`
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY StudentID
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db27c/4)

Comment: A very nice and straight-forward solution. The alias "subjects" in your first query should be accessable in a HAVING clause, however, so you can simply ask `HAVING subjects IS NOT NULL` and get rid of the outer query.

Comment: Nice catch. Yes, you can do it in MySQL but other major RDBMS system doesn't support that. I made this query in sql server so I had only two options, either use subquery or write the whole `case when` in `having clause`. we can modify it with having clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.stud_id, 
      (CASE WHEN A.stud_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) OnlyMaths, 
      (CASE WHEN B.stud_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) MatchsAndEnglish, 
      (CASE WHEN C.stud_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) MatchsAndEnglishANDScience
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT stud_id 
            FROM subj_assign 
            WHERE subj_id = 1 AND STATUS =  '1'
          ) AS A ON s.stud_id = A.stud_id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT stud_id 
            FROM subj_assign 
            WHERE subj_id IN (1, 3) AND STATUS =  '1'
            GROUP BY StudentID 
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subj_id) = 2
          ) AS B ON s.stud_id = B.stud_id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT stud_id 
            FROM subj_assign 
            WHERE subj_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND STATUS =  '1'
            GROUP BY StudentID 
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subj_id) = 3
          ) AS C ON s.stud_id = C.stud_id
```

Comment: Your first query to find students who registered only in maths will fail. This will select even the student  registered in some other course

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter the group using `Having Clause`. I don't know why you need all the results in a single query. Try this.

```
SELECT StudentID,
       'Only Maths' as Subjects
FROM   #testt
GROUP  BY StudentID
HAVING Count(CASE WHEN SubCode = '1' THEN 1 END) = 1
       AND Count(*) = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT StudentID,
       'Maths and English'
FROM   #testt
GROUP  BY StudentID
HAVING Count(CASE WHEN SubCode = '1' THEN 1 END) = 1
       AND Count(CASE WHEN SubCode = '3' THEN 1 END) = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT StudentID,
       'Maths,Sceince and English'
FROM   #testt
GROUP  BY StudentID
HAVING Count(CASE WHEN SubCode = '1' THEN 1 END) = 1
       AND Count(CASE WHEN SubCode = '3' THEN 1 END) = 1
       AND Count(CASE WHEN SubCode = '2' THEN 1 END) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` to clumb records returned from multiple queries.

```
select * from table where subName like 'Math'
union 
select * from table where subName like 'Math' and subName like 'English'
union 
select * from table where subName like 'Math' and subName like 'English' and subName like 'Science'
```

Comment: this wil not work . because second and third point is student who have registered in all three or maths and English both subject

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have shown the complete table, so there are just the three subjects, and provided student ID plus subject ID are unique for the table, simply sum the subject IDs:

```
select stud_id, group_concat(sub_name)
from subj_assign
group by stud_id
having sum(subj_id) = 1 -- Math only
or sum(subj_id) = 4 -- Math and English only
or sum(subj_id) = 6 -- Math and English and Science
order by stud_id asc;
```

In case the table contains more subjects:

```
select stud_id, group_concat(sub_name)
from subj_assign
group by stud_id
having sum(subj_id) = 1 -- Math only
or (min(subj_id) = 1 and max(subj_id) = 3 and sum(subj_id) = 4) -- Math and English only
or (min(subj_id) = 1 and max(subj_id) = 3 and sum(subj_id) = 6) -- Math and English and Science
order by stud_id asc;
```

There are many other aggregations you could use for evaluation, of course, such as `count(*)`, `count(case when ... end)` or `max(case when ... end)`.

Comment: 2 question is not to find `Math and English only`. You need to find students registered in Maths and English

Comment: @NoDisplayName: I think it was just forgotten to say this explicitely, because otherwise the third criteria would be superfluous.